# Firefox crashing on Heavy JS unless I move the mouse

Tags: javascript, firefox, crash

I am generating an XML file in JS of a few hundred lines. It works fine on Chrome and IE, but firefox keeps crashing.

However, the really odd thing is that firefox does not crash is I keep moving my mouse over my website.

I tried in v30.0 and v31.0.

I don't know if the bug if coming from firefox or my own code.

What do you think?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you report this as a Firefox bug, with the crash ID that you get from about:crashes, that may help you get an answer. Here's the URL to report a Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Firefox